# SQL join under a double condition

Tags: sql, join

Imagine we have 2 Tables, `A` and `B`, having the same structure, as follows:
`Currency`, `Spot`, `Exposure`, `Fixing`.

We want to join these two tables in order to have a query on, for example, `Fixing = '2013-01-03'` and having the major list of currencies (there is not always correspondence between currencies in `A` and currencies in `B`).

- 1 condition: `A.Fixing = B.Fixing`
- 2 condition: `A.Currency = B.Currency` (returning also Currency values not matched)

This is an example: We have the USD currency in table `A` for that day requested but we don't have it on table B. What we want for that day is a join table having one row with USD followed by the Exposure value in Table `A` and followed by zero (because ARS was not in table B and therefore it has no Exposure on USD)

How can we write a query?

Below Tables and results:

Table `A`:

```
Currency  Spot     Exposure      Fixing
--------  -------  ------------  ----------
AUD       1.3023   -504,561.00   30/01/2013
CHF       1.2378   268,243.00    30/01/2013
GBP       0.8597   2,204.00      30/01/2013
JPY       123.635  -552.00       30/01/2013
USD       1.3572   5,242.00      30/01/2013
AUD       1.300    -574,561.00   29/01/2013
CHF       1.235    545,152.00    29/01/2013
GBP       0.858    1,155,212.00  29/01/2013
JPY       123.388  -45,115.00    29/01/2013
USD       1.354    22,468.00     29/01/2013
```

Table `B`:

```
Currency  Spot     Exposure       Fixing
--------  -------  -------------  ----------
AUD       1.3023   256,442.00     30/01/2013
CHF       1.2378   -4,456,421.00  30/01/2013
GBP       0.8597   15,246.00      30/01/2013
JPY       123.635  1,243,146.00   30/01/2013
AUD       1.300    41,246.00      29/01/2013
CHF       1.235    243.00         29/01/2013
GBP       0.858    54,564.00      29/01/2013
JPY       123.388  140.00         29/01/2013
```

Results:

```
Currency  A.Exposure   B.Exposure     Fixing
--------  -----------  -------------  ----------
AUD       -504,561.00  256,442.00     30/01/2013
CHF       268,243.00   -4,456,421.00  30/01/2013
GBP       2,204.00     15,246.00      30/01/2013
JPY       -552.00      1,243,146.00   30/01/2013
USD       5,242.00     -              30/01/2013
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: Just added Tables and Results expected under Fixing = '2013-01-30'

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: The left outer join allows you to grab everything in table a and matching values in table b and having NULLs where there isn't data in table b.  Use the ISNULL() function to give you cleaner results by checking for NULL values and if it finds one, replacing it with a different value of your choosing.

```
select
  a.Currency
, a.Spot
, a.Exposure as a_Exposure
, ISNULL(b.Exposure, 0) as b_Exposure
, a.Fixing
from a
left outer join b 
   on b.Currency = a.Currency
   and b.Fixing = a.Fixing
where a.Fixing = '2013-01-30';
```

I have changed the query to reflect the suggestion from Clockwork-Muse.  You will need to add any columns you want data returned for.

Comment: I mean the original structure of Tables have more columns that the one I posted as example... does this interfere with the query?

Comment: Well, you will want to select all of the fields/columns that you want data from.  The spot=spot is not mandatory but if it is a true statement, it will help keep your results unique since you don't have a true unique key relationship between the tables (or do you?).

Comment: If you don't mind the order of the columns, you could use:  select a.*, b.exposure from table_a....

Otherwise you need to specify the columns and put them in the order you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, putting the 'extra' conditions in the `WHERE` clause turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (effectively, if not actually by the optimizer).  [Look at this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96bf1/9) (query errors fixed so it runs, period).  You're on the right track, though; moving the remaining conditions to be part of the join should fix the issue.  Personally, I always try to put as many relevant conditions as possible into the join clause, _especially_ in the case of `LEFT JOIN`s.  Oh, as the OP didn't list it, assuming `spot` is equal is unfounded.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, thanks for the tip and the example.  I keep forgetting to use slq fiddle to test my code before posting.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun.  This query isn't returning the correct results.  Let me find out what's up with it.

Comment: You're missing `b.fixing = a.fixing` from the join condition now.  Those are the only two conditions the OP lists, so those are the only ones we can rely on.

Comment: Thanks again Clockwork-Muse!  I was wondering why the results were off.  Using Spot works as well but like you said, it's not specified as a valid join.